# Multiple equation in one line with a separation

Tags: equations

Let's say I  have two set of formulaes that are grouped by pair because they are close to each other. I have currently this :

```
\begin{align} a &=\int_{}b\mathrm{d}x = c\\
\label{e1}
d &=\int_{} e \text{ d}x = f
\label{e2}
\end{align}

\begin{align} a^{\ast} &=\int_{}b^{\ast}\text{ d}x = g\\
\label{e1}
d^{\ast} &=\int_{} e^{\ast} \mathrm{d}x = h
\label{e}
\end{align}
```

which gives me the left part of my picture hereafter :

[image]

I'd like to get the right one in LaTeX, however i've no clue how to proceed. Any help ?

Comment: Add more &s in each line.  Every other & causes a gap instead of aligning the location.

Comment: `\displaystyle d` is the same as `d` (a displaystyle d is same as textstyle d, and you are already in displaystyle ayway) also don't use `\text{d}` for upright, use `\mathrm{d}`

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{align}
    a = & \int_{}b\mathrm{d}x = c & a^{\ast} = & \int_{}b^{\ast}\text{ d}x = g \\
    d = & \int_{} e \text{ d}x = f &    d^{\ast} =& \int_{} e^{\ast} \mathrm{d}x = h
    \end{align}  

\end{document}
```

[image]